# Is there any other way to say "I don't care" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice, phrase, phrase-request

Is there any other phrase to express "Das ist mir egal" (I don't care) in German?

Comment: I've seen sometimes "Das ist mir gleich".

Comment: Imho another prominent (informal) example: Das ist mir schnuppe!

Comment: Das ist mir [insert any word you like].

Comment: @Em1: "Das ist mir Rotationsellipsoid" -- I really like that word, but that's not as snappy as you'd like. :/

Comment: This question is also discussed [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34822/polite-way-to-say-i-dont-care-das-ist-mir-egal/34828)

Comment: "Drauf geschissen!", although that's more along the lines of "We shall not care about that".

Answer (score 25):

Plenty, with slight differences in connotation and usage possibilities.
For example:

- (Das ist mir) Egal. <sup>$</sup>
- Das ist mir einerlei. <sup>$</sup>
- Mir doch egal.
- (Das) Ist mir gleich. <sup>$</sup>
- (Das) Ist mir Wurscht/Latte/Schnuppe/Wumpe/Hupe... <sup>#</sup>
- Wie/Was/Wo... auch immer.
- Meinetwegen. <sup>$</sup>
- Das kümmert mich nicht. <sup>$</sup>
- Das juckt mich nicht.
- Das schert mich nicht.
- Das kratzt mich nicht.
- Das geht mir am Arsch vorbei. <sup>#</sup>
- Der kann mir (damit) gestohlen bleiben. <sup>#</sup>

Many such phrases are probably regional, and certainly colloquial.

If you are in a formal or any situation that mandates a certain politeness, I recommend you stick to one of the phrases I marked with <sup>$</sup>. Be careful with the ones marked <sup>#</sup>.

Comment: Mir egal, Das ist mir Bums, Scheiß/kackegal, ....

Comment: I might add, that some of the proposed solutions are - while technically correct - on a different (=lower) level of politeness and not as neutral as "I don't care".

Comment: @StefanSchroeder: Definitely. I though about classifying/ordering them w.r.t. connotation but decided that tone and emphasis had too much an impact for such a classification to be useful. I marked some that I think can safely be used in a polite way (and afaik all over Germany). YMMV.

Comment: @Raphael Maybe I am an impolite person but even in formal situations I feel free to say "das schert mich nicht". It has a tiny hint of aggression in it but aggression (to a degree) and politeness are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Einer As I said, any such attempt at classification is going to be incomplete and inaccurate in some circumstances. (Not being marked with $ does not mean the phrase is rude, btw; it just means you should stick to those with $ if you want to be safe -- imho.)

Answer (score 6):

I'm personally fond of

> Das interessiert mich nicht die Bohne.

or

> sich nicht die Bohne für *etw.* interessieren.

I guess it's kind of obvious that it's very colloquial.

Answer (score 6):

Besonders in Österreich sehr beliebt ist:

> Das ist mir wurst.

Dabei wird das Wort "wurst" häufig wie "wurscht" ausgesprochen, was aber auch auf die Wurst zutrifft, die man essen kann.

Die Gewinnerin des letzten Eurovision Songcontests, Conchita Wurst, hat (unter anderem) daraus den Nachnamen ihres Künstlernamens abgeleitet. (Weil es wurst ist, ob man Mann oder Frau ist) (Der zweite Grund für den Namen "Wurst" ist die Ähnlichkeit einer Wurst mit männlichen Genitalien, als Kontrast zu "Conchita", womit vor allem in Lateinamerika weibliche Genitalien bezeichnet werden.)

Answer (score 4):

Zu Raphaels erstaunlich langer Liste möchte ich eine Variante ergänzen, in der nicht der Unterton des Genervtseins mitschwingt und deswegen auch für Schriftform taugt:

> Das macht mir nichts aus.

Answer (score 1):

There are a multitude of possibilities, those depending on formality, dialect, and so on.

[Here](http://www.dict.cc/?s=I%20don%27t%20care) for example, is a pretty good list of different options. My personal favorite would be "Ist mir Wurst", preferably pronounced "Isch mir Wurscht" :)

Answer (score 1):

> "Ist mir egal"

can also have the meaning of

> "as you like"

it can mean that you are "indifferent" to some choices but your tone of voice is important (angry or relaxed...)

Comment: Surely the same is true for "I don't care"? It, too, can express simple indifference as well.

Answer (score 1):

- *Meh!* / *Hmh!*
- *Ph!* / *Pff!*
- *Mach ma’!*
- *Wie du willst/meinst!*
- *Mach wie du willst/meinst/denkst!*
- *Ich bin da flexibel/nicht festgelegt/völlig frei/offen für alles.*
- ‍♂️/‍♀️/**schulterzuck**
- 
- *Wayne/Wen [interessiert’s]?*

Answer (score 0):

In my region (Bavaria, university age) we sometimes even use

> "Das ist mir relativ same"

("It's all the same to me" more or less), which of course originates from the language used on the internet. It's pretty informal, though.